# Change state with StateProvider to change background image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management, riverpod

I want to change the background image with a tap on the list tile in ListView using Riverpod state management. I get a list of movies from the API of MovieDB and want to show them on the main page then when a user taps on a list tile the background image changes to a new image
I tried this:

```
final selectedMoviePosterURLProvider = StateProvider<String?>((ref) {
  final List<Movie> _movies = ref.watch(mainPageDataControllerProvider).movies;
  //set default image after launch the app
  return _movies.isNotEmpty ? _movies[0].posterUrl : null;
});
class MainPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  late String? _selectedMoviePosterURL;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    _selectedMoviePosterURL = ref.watch(selectedMoviePosterURLProvider);
    return _buildUI();
  }
  Widget _buildUI() => Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              _backgroundWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _backgroundWidget() {
    if (_selectedMoviePosterURL != null) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            //we provide _selectedMoviePoster here to update background image
            image: NetworkImage(_selectedMoviePosterURL!),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return const SizedBox.expand();
    }
  }
  Widget _movieListViewWidget() {
    final List<Movie> _movies = _mainPageData.movies;

    if (_movies.isNotEmpty) {
      return NotificationListener(
        onNotification: (_onScrollNotification) {....},
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _movies.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext _context, int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: _deviceHeight * 0.01, horizontal: 0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: MovieTile(...),
                  onTap: () {
                    // we want to update UI after user tap on a list tile
                    _selectedMoviePosterURL = _movies[index].posterUrl;
                  },
                ),
              );
            }),
      );
    } else {
       ....
    }
  }
}
```

How can we update the UI with the `_selectedMoviePosterURL` variable like calling `setState` when changing variables in Stateful widgets?

Comment: The last version of riverpod said : ref.read(selectedMoviePosterURLProvider.state).update((state) => _movies[index].posterUrl);

Comment: @mariofrancois I don't have access to ref in onTap. how can I access it without drilling?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than assigning the URL directly you would want to use:

```
ref.read(selectedMoviePosterURLProvider.notifier).state = _movies[index].posterUrl;
```

This will trigger a re-build of your MainPage widget.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have access to the ref inside the _movieListViewWidget function, so how can I use it?

Comment: You can a) pass the ref through your chain of methods, b) refactor your methods into individual consumer widgets so they each get access to a ref, or c) convert MainPage into a ConsumerStatefulWidget so ref becomes a member of the class and you can access it from any method. I would recommend option b for the long-term maintainability of your app.